# Fourier analysis with Galois Theory

Tags: fourier-analysis, galois-theory

Do you know some combinations between Galois theory and Fourier analysis and what are the applications?

Comment: If we say that mathematics is divided into $N$ fields – where $N$ is quite large – then one can generate $N(N-1)/2$ questions of this form without any thought whatsoever.

Comment: The Lagrange resolvent: http://home.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/~wkshum/wordpress/?p=152